# Make a word in a TextBlock bold

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

So I have some XAML which makes certain words bold

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Instructions">
  This text is normal <bold> this text is bold </bold>
</TextBlock>
```

However I need to be able to do this through C#, as I dynamically change instrcutions e.g.

```
String Instruction1 = "Do something to <bold> item x </bold>"
String Instruction2 = "Do something to <bold> item y </bold>"
```

I know the string doesn't deal with any formatting, but I'm not sure how to manipulate the `TextBox` to do this for me.

Comment: Use `Inlines`, as shown in the answer to your previous question.

Comment: That allows me to a add a fully bold string, no a string made up of different styles?

Comment: Can you unmark this as a duplicate.. the previous answer doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: In case this is a question about how to use Inlines in a Windows Store app, you should not tag it as WPF. WPF *is not used* for Windows Store apps.

Comment: The Run class only has a default constructor in Windows Runtime. Set the Text property instead. And use `Bold` objects to start a bold text section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution

```
Run bold = new Run();
bold.Text = "Should be bold";

bold.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;

BlockInstructions.Inlines.Add(bold);



Run notbold = new Run();
notbold.Text = "Shouldn't be bold";

notbold.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;

BlockInstructions.Inlines.Add(notbold);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use markup text. Check this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234651/Basic-HTML-Markup-in-WPF-TextBlock

**UPDATE**

I know this is not what you asked, but maybe you can find it helpful (the code project library made me curious).

```
XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse("<root><b>Should be bold</b>Shouldn't be bold</root>");
AddRuns(BlockInstructions.Inlines, xmlTree);

void AddRuns(InlineCollection inlines, XNode node, bool isBold = false, bool  isItalic = false)
{   
    var inline = new Run {
        FontWeight = isBold ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal,
        FontStyle = isItalic ? FontStyles.Italic : FontStyles.Normal
    };
    inlines.Add(inline);

    var element = node as XElement;
    if (null != element)
    {
        foreach (var item in element.Nodes())
        {
            AddRuns(
                inline.SiblingInlines,
                item,
                element.Name.LocalName == "b" || isBold,
                element.Name.LocalName == "i" || isItalic
            );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        inline.Text = Convert.ToString(node);
    }
}
```